# Not able to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

Tags: system-installation

I have tried several times to install Ubuntu on my laptop alongside Windows 10 as recommended in the Mag LINUX FORMAT but when I get to Installation type I only get /dev/sda and no other choice.

I have created an 80 Gb partition etc. but it doesn't make any difference.

The only issue I have had is that when I re-created the partition using gparted I got a message about 512 and 2048 that I didn't understand.

I have had another Linux distro installed before and it wasn't any problem to get it installed along side Windows 10 etc.

What do I need to do to solve my problem?

Comment: It sounds like it's a GPT disk and gparted only works on MBR disks. I haven't read "the Mag LINUX FORMAT" but I would suggest using the instructions for installing Ubuntu alongside Windows on this site instead. https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069

Comment: gparted works on gpt disks just fine